# CreateWindow “Edit” typed characters are 'invisible'?

Tags: winapi, edit

After having researched all I could find on the proper syntax for the `CreateWindow("Edit")` call, I have to throw in the towel: when I run the program, all I get in the Edit box is "invisible characters". The cursor is moving right as I type, but the characters I enter are nowhere to be seen. Only when I select the box content with the mouse do I see the text. But as soon as I release the mouse, I can not longer see anything.

Here is the entire code which leads to 'text not showing' in the Edit control:

```
#include <windows.h>

#define FILE_MENU_NEW 1
#define FILE_MENU_OPEN 2
#define FILE_MENU_QUIT 3
#define CHANGE_TITLE 4

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
void AddMenus(HWND);
void AddControls(HWND);     
HMENU hMenu;
HWND hEdit;

int WINAPI wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance, _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, _In_ LPWSTR lpCmdLine, _In_ int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASS wc = {0}; // Assign 0 to all its elements initialy
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"myWindowClass";
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc; // this is a pointer to a function

    if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
        return -1;

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,                               
        L"myWindowClass",                           
        L"Learn to Program Windows - Roger Breton",     
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE ,              
        100, 100, 800, 600,
        NULL,       
        NULL,       
        hInstance, 
        NULL        
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch(wParam)
        {
        case FILE_MENU_QUIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);    
            break;

        case FILE_MENU_NEW:
            MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
            break;

        case CHANGE_TITLE:
            wchar_t text[100];
            GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);   
            SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
            break;
        }

    case WM_CREATE:             
        AddMenus(hWnd);
        AddControls(hWnd);
        break;

    case WM_DESTROY:                
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW));
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }

    return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

void AddMenus(HWND hWnd)    
{
    hMenu = CreateMenu(); 
    HMENU hFileMenu = CreateMenu();
    HMENU hSubMenu = CreateMenu(); 
    AppendMenu(hSubMenu, MF_STRING, NULL, L"Sub-Menu");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_NEW, L"New");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hSubMenu, L"Sub-menu ");
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_SEPARATOR, NULL, NULL);
    AppendMenu(hFileMenu, MF_STRING, FILE_MENU_QUIT, L"Quit");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_POPUP, (UINT_PTR)hFileMenu, L"File");
    AppendMenu(hMenu, MF_STRING, NULL, L"Aide");
    SetMenu(hWnd, hMenu);    
}

void AddControls(HWND hWnd) 
{
    CreateWindowW(L"Static", L"Enter text here:", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER , 200, 100, 150, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        hEdit = CreateWindowW(L"Edit", NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER , 200, 152, 100, 50, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowW(L"Button", L"Changez title", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 200, 204, 150, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)CHANGE_TITLE, NULL, NULL); 
}
```

I tried to recreate the source file many times, to no avail.

Comment: The proper way to deai with your question being closed is to edit it and add the new information there, not to post a duplicate with the additional information added. You can find that information in the [help].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CreateWindow "Edit" typed characters are 'invisible'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341507/createwindow-edit-typed-characters-are-invisible) (Duplicate by same author)

Comment: @KenWhite I agree with your comment but I was not aware of that other post when I posted my answer. Maybe the earlier question can just be deleted, as this one is clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a missing `break;` statement at the end of your `case WM_COMMAND:` block. As it stands, your code will 'fall through' to the `case WM_CREATE:` code after processing *any* `WM_COMMAND`.

Adding that `break;` statement appears to fix your code (when I test it):

```c
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)     {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch (wParam)         {
                case FILE_MENU_QUIT:
                    DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                    break;
                case FILE_MENU_NEW:
                    MessageBeep(MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                    break;
                case CHANGE_TITLE:
                    wchar_t text[100];
                    GetWindowTextW(hEdit, text, 100);
                    SetWindowTextW(hWnd, text);
                    break;
            }
            break; // ** You missed this line! **
        case WM_CREATE:
            AddMenus(hWnd);
            AddControls(hWnd);
            break;
//...
```

Such mistakes can be spotted if you enable all compiler warnings: The static code analyser in MSVC gives the following message:

> warning C26819: Unannotated fallthrough between switch labels (es.78).

Comment: you nailed it right on! I'm surprised, though, the compiler BY DEFAULT didn't pick that kind of error up? I'll take a look on how to turn the static code analyser in VS2019!!! You have "freed me" -- now I can continue on the next step on my humble project!

Comment: The thing is, omitting that `break` statement isn't actually an *error* in the strictest sense of the compiler's point-of-view; it's valid C and C++ syntax but just *not* what you intended.

Comment: @All - I wish I could Edit my post, to add the "solution" (missing 'break,' statement) but the site says "Suggested edit queue is full".

Comment: @RogerBreton  Actually, you should *never* edit a question to add a solution, once that solution has been posted as an answer! Doing so would defeat the purpose of this Q/A format site.

Comment: I completely missed the CheckMark :-)